# rails devise current_user, catching ldap errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

rails (5.0.0.1)

ruby (2.3.1)

We are hitting some LDAP errors (very occasionally) where are infrastructure servers (which we do not maintain) are closing the connection earlier Errno::ECONNRESET errors.

I was attempting to catch errors with current_user with a retry but hitting some interesting scenarios.  The first call to "current_user.try(:username)" throws the ldap error expected (to reproduce I gave it a bad server address that should always fail).  After hitting the retry the second call to "current_user.try(:username)" doesn't throw an error but current_user is still nil.  Apologies for the ugly debug code

```
def do_current_user
  count = 0
  begin
    logger.error "Try in do_current_user #{count}"
    if current_user.nil?
      logger.error "Current_user is nill at count #{count}"
    end
    current_user.try(:username)
  rescue Errno::ECONNRESET, Net::LDAP::Error => e
    count = count + 1
    logger.error "Exception hit with authenticate \n#{e.backtrace.join("\n\t")}\n Retrying the request"
    retry if count < 3
  end
end
```

Not sure if anyone else has any hints on this one.  There isn't a lot to the helper in devise/controllers/helpers.rb; might could have in one but from initial looks would appear to be something caching deeper in ldap modules:

```
      def current_#{mapping}
        @current_#{mapping} ||= warden.authenticate(scope: :#{mapping})
      end
```